# angular ui modal can NOT refer to parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

i am using angular ui modal to create modal in my project.

Everything works fine until I need to refer to variable in parent scope. see [plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ub0dAB?p=preview)

It seems like modal can't access parent scope. Is there anyway to overcome this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Angular UI's modals use `$rootScope` by default [(See the documentation here)](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

You can pass a `scope` parameter with a custom scope when you open the modal – e.g. `scope: $scope` if you want to pass the parent scope. The modal controller will create a sub-scope from that scope, so you will only be able to use it for your initial values.

Comment: the doc you provided does not exist, can you provide a new one?

Comment: Apparently you can't anchor-link their documentation. Go on the documentation and find the *modal* heading.

Comment: What would be the solution to have the child scope dynamically update when the parent scope values change? This is really critical for me as I have a data polling event that updates the data shown in my modals and I want them to update dynamically. Thanks!

Comment: @tpartee you should post a new question for that. This is not something to answer in the comments.

Answer (score 16):

You'll need to refer to the parent scope in your $modal options. [Angular documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

[Corrected Plunker Version](http://plnkr.co/edit/HpyjYaVsAtQhvIJ3UWzE?p=info)

Below is also a code snippet of what I added to make it work.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  scope:$scope, //Refer to parent scope here
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ID to the parent div and use his scope.

```
<div id="outerdiv"  ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
<h2>Outer Controller</h2>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkBind">
<p>Value Of checkbind: {{checkBind}}</p>
```

And set up a "fake" binding within the controller

```
//init
$scope.checkBind = angular.element(document.getElementById('outerdiv')).scope().checkBind;

  $scope.$watch('checkBind', function (newValue, oldValue) {
//update parent
  angular.element(document.getElementById('outerdiv')).scope().checkBind = $scope.checkBind;
  });
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/u6DuoHJmOctFLFhvqCME?p=preview