# Cannot Access parent controller's method from the child UI

Tags: angularjs

I have a popup form where it's having lot of tabs.

Its' like this :

*index.js*

```
vm.openCreateOrEditPropertyModal = function (resolveProperty) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/createOrEditPropertyModal.cshtml',
        controller: 'tenant.views.propertymanagement.createOrEditPropertyModal as vm',
       resolve: {
              resolveProperty: function () {
              return resolveProperty;
                }
               }
                });
        };
```

Tabs are like this :

*createOrEditPropertyModal.cshtml*

```
<uib-tabset class="tab-container tabbable-line" type="pills">
  <uib-tab heading="@L("PropertyInformation")">
       <div ng-include="'~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/tabs/propertyForm.cshtml'"></div>
      </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

*createOrEditPropertyModal.js*

```
(function () {
    appModule.controller("tenant.views.propertymanagement.createOrEditPropertyModal", [
        "$scope", "resolveProperty", "localStorageService", "$uibModalInstance", function ($scope, resolveProperty, localStorageService, $uibModalInstance) {

            var vm = this;


            //to close the pop up
            vm.cancel = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

*propertyForm.cshtml*

```
<div ng-controller="tenant.views.propertymanagement.tabs.propertyForm as vm">
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.cancel()">@L("Close")</button>
</div>
```

*propertyForm.js*

```
(function () {
    appModule.controller("tenant.views.propertymanagement.propertyForm", [
        "$scope", "resolveProperty", "localStorageService", function ($scope, resolveProperty, localStorageService) {

            var vm = this;



        }
    ]);
})();
```

Above set up is working fine.Now I need to access `cancel()` method on the `createOrEditPropertyModal.js` file from the child form (i.e. `propertyForm.cshtml`).But it's not being fired.Can you tell me how to do that ? I have tried like this `ng-click="$parent.cancel()"`.But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `vm.cancel()` directly inside a child form as you are already using controllerAs pattern. But in your case you have both controller alias as `vm` it is referring to current child controller context. Changing name of either of controller alias would make it working.

Best way to solve this issue would change your controller alias to different name. Controller aaliases should be like by looking at their name's you can pretend which controller it is.

--

The `ng-click` isn't working because `cancel` method isn't there inside `$parent` scope. You should be doing `$parent.vm.cancel()`. But I'd not prefer you to use `$parent` on view, because bad practice.

Comment: Actually my set up is like that.I have updated the question.Please see that.But that `cancel()` method is not being fired.Is that due to same name for the controllers ? I mean about the `vm`

Comment: Might be.. do try changing the name.. on view it must work

Comment: It's because your controller `propertyForm as vm` is shadowing `createOrEditPropertyModal as vm`.

Comment: Yes,now your 2nd option is working.Thanks for that.But can you tell me a best way to refactor this ?

Comment: Best way is to have different controller alias on view, inspite of having `vm` have some name which can describe which controller it is.

Comment: Hope I have to change the UI elements with the new alias name and no need to change anything within the controller no ?

Comment: I don't understand you last statement, if you don't wanted to changes in code? Why you are asking for best practices suggestions then?

Comment: Nope, I would like to do the code changes.This is my question.Let's say I have given alias as `pm`.Then I need to change all the UI elements like this `ng-model="pm.property.priority"` and so on.But on that controller where I can keep like this no `var vm = this;

            vm.saving = false;
            vm.property = {
                id: null
            };`  Am I wrong ?

Comment: No need to change controller code.. inside a controller `var vm` is just a variable name which holds reference of `this`, you need to changeview bindings only. That's it. Apologies, for my misunderstanding. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three possible solutions:

1. It's because the `cancel` function is not on the `$parent` scope, but on the parent controller. One way to achieve this is probably to use different naming for controllers: [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26309471/2419215)
2. Otherwise, you could put the `cancel` function on the `$scope` variable in `createOrEditPropertyModal`.

Just change `createOrEditPropertyModal.js`:

```
vm.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
};
```

to

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
};
```

3. You can pass functions to modals similar to directives: [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24205587/2419215)

Comment: The second solution might not work because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780181/angular-ui-modal-can-not-refer-to-parent-scope. Please let me know, and I'll update my answer

Comment: Can you tell me little bit more about the 2nd option ? May be simple code snippet.

Comment: Yes,Now it is working.Thanks for that.But I think this is not a good way to handle parent/child reference no ? What is your thoughts ? If I change the different names for the controllers then I think I have to change all the UI components names also no ? Which method do you think is better when we consider the maintainability and etc ?

Comment: @Sampath I don't know if you tried, but I'd prefer the third one if you can pass the cancel function by the time of instantiation. Using the named controllers is probably not a good idea, as it prevents reusability, same for accessing the parent. Which one worked btw? If one of them is not working I'd rather delete it.

Comment: Your 3rd solution may be worked for this situation.But how can I share the data between controllers ? Let's say I need to use the parent ctrl's `propertId` within my child ctrl. Then how can I do that ? Again I have to face the same issue no ?

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to use directives (think of component architecture) and pass data in `bindToController`. https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/. It's like a defined interface, so it removes the implicitness

Comment: Thanks a lot for your invaluable suggestions. +1 :)